# To get time along with Date from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#

I have a datetimepicker whose format is short.I have to get time along with date in code behind.Now 12:00:00 am is inserting along with date.Instead i need to insert current time along with date picked from datetimepicker.Can anybody help?

Answer (score 3):

Create a new `DateTime` using the date from your input and the time from `DateTime.Now`.

```
DateTime GetDateAndCurrentTime(DateTime date)
{
    return new DateTime(date.Year, date.Month, date.Day, DateTime.Now.Hour, DateTime.Now.Minute, DateTime.Now.Second);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The actual DateTime.Value from the picker is a full DateTime object with the current time.

```
private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;
        // or
        string s = string.Concat(dt.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString());
    }
```

Comment: I agree, that is correct. `DateTime dt = dateTimePicker1.Value;`

Answer (score 0):

Full DateTime:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value;
```

> '08/21/2011 14:42:11'

Short DateTime:

```
dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
```

> '08/21/2011 00:00:00'

The **minimum** value

> '08/21/2011 00:00:00'

The **maximum** value

> '08/21/2011 23:59:59'

**Usage:**

```
   var firstDate = dtpFrom.Value.Date; //  0:00:00
   var secondDate =  dtpTo.Value.Date.AddSeconds(86400 - 1); //23:59:59 - 86400 is 24 hours
   var list = Services.GetListForFilter(firstDate, secondDate);
```